# Where is the CodeNameOne Designer Heap setting?

Tags: java, macos, netbeans, codenameone

Where is the CodeNameOne Designer Heap setting? I keep getting a crash on OSX because it is running out of heap. I upped the NetBeans heap, but I am guessing that CodeNameOne's Designer does not use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next update to have a larger than default value. There is no explicit setting for that but you can invoke the designer from command line as such:

```
java -Xmx256m -jar ~/.codenameone/designer_1.jar
```